# Can Azure Backup server be installed on same server as workload?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-backup-vault

Is it possible to install azure backup server on same server as workload or does it require separate server?

And does it support backup of SQL 2014 Express edition?

Comment: How did yo backup your server? As I known, if you use Azure Back up service for azure IaaS VM, the backup is stored as a backup vault in Azure Recovery service. So it cannot be installed on same server as workload.  Also, if your SQL is installed in a VM, Azure Back up service supports all of VM backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it requires **separate** server, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup).

> Azure Backup Server is designed to run on a **dedicated,
>   single-purpose server**. You cannot install Azure Backup Server on:
>
> - A computer running as a domain controller
> - A computer on which the Application Server role is installed
> - A computer that is a System Center Operations Manager management server
> - A computer on which Exchange Server is running
> - A computer that is a node of a cluster

For the **supported version** of SQL Server, you could refer to [**Azure Backup Server protection matrix**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-mabs-protection-matrix).

[image]